# component not found when deploy on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, netlify, vite

I'm trying to deploy my test app site build with `Vite` and `Vue 3` on `Netlify`. It´s a very simple project, with two pages and simple components. Building in my laptop works fine, but not when I try to deploy it.

*Local*

[image: local build]

But in `Netlify`

[image: netlify build]

I don't really know how to solve this. My source code is [here](https://github.com/Aw3same/workflow-landing-page)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: typo. change `import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'` to `import Navbar from '@/components/NavBar.vue'`

Comment: what's the difference between? I can't see any

Comment: Navbar -> NavBar

Comment: Ok! in this way works fine. But why works in my local environment?

Comment: well i cant answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ifaruki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10990737/ifaruki), the solution was easy (a typo change):

I have to change my import in `App.vue` from this :

```js
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
```

to

```js
import Navbar from '@/components/NavBar.vue'
```